# I'm strugling with strcmp in c

Tags: c

i'm struggling to compare user input with the file contents. Basically i created a function that updates employee details that first prompts for the name of the employee and then it compares the name entered with those in the file. I tried doing this:

```
void update(EMPLOYEE *details)
{
    FILE *file;
    char search;
    file = fopen("employees.txt","r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File error!!!");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        search = getc(file);
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s",details->name);

        if((strcmp(search,details->name) == 0))
        {
            printf("%s\n",details->name);
            printf("%d",details->employeeNumber);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: getc returns a single character (letter). You'll need to read an entire word from the file and pass that to strcmp instead.

Comment: With those in the file... but (a) you do not iterate, (b) where do you read the name from the file (getc reads the next char..) and (c) what is the actual problem you have...

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing a single character, `search` with (I assume) an entire string, `details->name`.

The method signature for [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) is:

```
int strcmp (const char *str1, const char *str2);
```

You are calling it as:

```
int strcmp (const char str1, const char *str2);
```

Not only this, but you are going to read past your str1 character buffer if you fix it to make it compile unless it happens to be character 0, which it won't be.

To fix this, you must do one of the following:

- Change your comparison to look at just the first characters.
- Change your search variable to be a string (probably char[]) and read in an entire string, then compare.

Comment: my problem is that i want to enter a name then check if the name is in the file file. If the name is in the file then then the details of the employee should be displayed

Comment: @Talra You need to mix my answer with Mario's answer. Loop through each user and read it in. Then, read in user input as a string (e.g., `char search[90]; if (fgets(search, 90, stdin) != NULL) { /* compare */ }`) and compare the strings using `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` takes a string (`char *`) not a single letter.  As others have mentioned in the comments, you need to update the `getc` process to read more than the single letter.

Answer (score 0):

a hint:

```
EMPLOYEE fileData;

while ( fread( &fileData, sizeof( fileData ), 1, file ) == sizeof( fileData )
{
...
}
```

EDIT: changed read to fread since it is a FILE*

hth

Comment: should i do that in the function itself or in the main?

Comment: function. this will allow you to read all the records (assuming that you wrote EMPLOYEE's to the file)